# Abrir archivo .txt como bytes en C#

Tags: c#, archivo

Mi clase tiene que abrir un archivo .txt el cual contiene algunos caracteres en ASCII, al abrirlo, dicho archivo debo de almacenarlo en un byte[], para poder extraer algunas ubicaciones específicas del documento y así como poder modificarlo

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: vas a tener que agregar lo que hiciste hasta ahora. y especificar cual es el problema especifico que estas teniendo

Comment: `byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("MiArchivo.txt");` ¿No te sirve?

Answer (score 2):

[`System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(nombreArchivo)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Este metodo retorna el contenido de un archivo en forma de `byte[]`.

Ejemplo:

```
byte[] contenido = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("c:/miarchivoTexto.txt");
```

Comment: Hola.. aunque la respuesta sea correcta, podrias agregar un poco mas de informacion respecto de que hace la funcion, o como se usa, o hasta que devuelve? solo como registro para futuros usuarios.